# Excel chart major gridlines based on a percentage change from previous major gridline value?

Tags: microsoft-excel

On a chart, I would like to be able to set a horizontal or vertical scale with a minimum value of say 60.

Then I would like the major gridlines labeled and to be placed at say a 5% increase from the previous gridline.

So in my example I want major gridlines at:
60.00
63.00
66.15
69.46
72.93
76.58
etc. until the scales max value is exceeded.

I know there is not a specific way to achieve this in the normal gridline setup, but is there a workaround way to do this?

Thanks,
Dale

Comment: This doesn't do exactly what you are asking, but you could right-click on an axis, choose "Format Axis" and select the option for a Logarithmic scale. See if that helps you achieve what you want.

Comment: Sorry that is only integer power of 10, as you say, not quite what I want, Thanks.  I'm ok even if I have to do it in a macro...